# My android app says source not found when i'm debugging it

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Hello I'm a college student studying Java. I'm working on a android application. It compiles and shows no error. However when it runs, there's a unexpected close error.

[image]

[image]

Here's my application. When you click on the calculate ws you purpose to change to this screen.

Here's my code:

```
package com.warhammerdicerrolleralpha;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class myMain extends Activity 
{

    EditText enternumberofdice;

    final TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);

    private EditText text, text2, text3;

    private Button btutorial1;

    int number1 = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());

    int number2 = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText().toString());

    ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
    {
        i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    }

    private int myFaceValue;

    int myNum;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void go() 
    {
        while (myNum > 0) 
        {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textGenerateNumber.setText(String.valueOf(enternumberofdice));

             --myNum;

            return;
        }
    }

    public int roll() 
    {
        int val = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1); // Range 1-6
        setValue(val);
        return val;
    }

    {
        try 
        {
            myNum = Integer.parseInt(enternumberofdice.getText().toString());
        } 
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) 
        {
            enternumberofdice.setText("Does not work");
        }
    }

    public int getValue() 
    {
        return myFaceValue;
    }

    public void setValue(int myFaceValue) 
    {
        this.myFaceValue = myFaceValue;

    }

    {
        switch (myFaceValue) 
        {
        case 5:
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicefive);
            break;
        case 1:
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.diceone);
            break;
        case 3:
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicethree);
            break;
        case 2:
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicetwo);
            break;
        case 4:
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicefour);
            break;
        case 6:
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicesix);
            break;
        default:
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.error);
            break;
        }

        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        text2 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);      

        btutorial1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btutorial1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

        Button buttonGenerate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        enternumberofdice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enternumberofdice);

        Button buttonGenerate2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.battlecalculate);

        buttonGenerate2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()    
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
            }

        });

        buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()     
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                go();

                roll();
            }

        });
    }

    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        switch (view.getId()) 
        {
            case R.id.button1:

                if (number1 > number2) 
                {
                    text3.setText("Three and above");       
                    return;
                }

                else if (number1 < number2) 
                {
                    text3.setText("Five and above");        
                    return;
                }

                else if (number1 == number2) 
                {
                    text3.setText("Four and above");        
                    return;
                }

                else
                {
                    text3.setText("Not Working");       
                    return;
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: XML link is here [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?63b6set5cvxaln8)

Comment: I don't think many people will be interested in downloading a PDF of your XML file. Can you edit your question and paste the XML into it? Also, most people are going to going to ask you for your logcat output; it might not hurt to provide that as well.

Comment: I try adding my XML code, but I get In addition in the preview page.

Comment: Rob Hruska what did you change ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your stack trace, but I think it may be because of this block:

```
private EditText text, text2, text3;

private Button btutorial1;

int number1 = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());

int number2 = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText().toString());
```

It looks as though you are trying to parseInt over null values. You need to specify where text, text2, text3 are in your form using similar code to:

```
TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nope that didn't help but I'll keep the changes you advice.

Comment: [2011-03-13 20:27:30 - Logcat]device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:736)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:284)
 at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel$3.run(LogPanel.java:527)

[2011-03-13 20:47:31 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger

Comment: I don't know how to get a stack trace in java??